# Selecting rows and replace columns that have value less than specific value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with 30 numeric columns. I would like to select rows that have a value less than, for example, 50 in any column and replace it by the mean of the row. I tried doing the following but it didn't work.

```
dataset.where((dataset[:]>=50).any(axis=1), dataset.mean(axis=1), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `axis=0` to set a value for all columns.

You also need `pd.DataFrame.mask` instead of `pd.DataFrame.where` to change values where the specified criterion is `True`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[75, 100, 65],
                   [25, 25, 30],
                   [55, 90, 45],
                   [55, 90, 75]])

df.mask((df < 50).any(axis=1), df.mean(axis=1), axis=0, inplace=True)

print(df)

           0           1          2
0  75.000000  100.000000  65.000000
1  26.666667   26.666667  26.666667
2  63.333333   63.333333  63.333333
3  55.000000   90.000000  75.000000
```

Comment: why "45"  didnt change? it should be replaced by 63.33 (the mean of row)

Comment: @computerScience, It does change (in latest revision). I've kept things simple and use `df < 50` as in the description of your problem.

Comment: I'm completely confused. I run this code but I still have values less than 50 in my datafram!

Comment: @computerScience, Well, if you're replacing by the mean, then yes you will have numbers less than 50 (if the mean for a  row is less than 50).